# how to redirect to a page using ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my website, after the user logs in, and a successful login response follows as a result of ajax login request, I want the user to be redirected to a 'appusers/appusers', such that the request sent to the server side module 'appusers' is a post request with some params like limit, offset etc. How do I accomplish this with jquery on the client side?

Answer (score 6):

You can fill in fields of a POST form dynamically and trigger the `submit()` button and it will go to the action page set.

```
<form action="appusers/appusers" method="POST">
    <input id="limit" type="hidden" value="" name="limit" />
</form>
```

In the success function of the AJAX call,

```
$('#limit').val('My Limit');
$(form).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call for your login request like this for example:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: getSvcUrl(service, method),
        type: "GET",
        data: request,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: isAsync,
        success:                 redirectToPage();
        , ...
```

and in the `redirectToPage()` function called `onSuccess` you can do a `window.location="http://www.bing.com"` or a `location.replace("http://www.microsoft.com")` for a GET or submit a form for a POST ($(`"#myForm").submit()`)